# rails rest-client 1.6.7 gem doc ri and RDoc error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rest-client

So I am trying to run the ruby gem rest-client, and the gem installs, but then I get an error message for the ri and RDoc files.

```
ERROR: rdoc/README_rdoc.html: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with IBM437 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

rdoc lib README.rdoc history.md --title rest-client-1.6.7 Documentation --quiet
```

I have tried doing it with gem install rest-client-1.6.7 --no-rdoc --no-ri, but it says they could not find the valid gem 'rest-client-1.6.7'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Windows. [This](http://tinkeringruby.blogspot.com/2012/01/heroku-installation.html) worked for me:

```
> set RDOCOPT="--encoding=UTF-8"
> gem install heroku
```